# How GO To flow behaves/work, if PARA has only EXIT statement

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

For example what will be the output?

```
  PROCEDURE DIVISION
    MAINPARA
        DISPLAY "MAIN".
        GO TO PARA1.
        DISPLAY "DISPLAY".
        STOP RUN.

    PARA1.
        EXIT.

    PARA2.
        DISPLAY "I AM IN PARA2"
    ...
```

Will it execute PARA2 or not?

I am not a COBOL programmer, and I need to understand code from a migration tool/process, AMXW COBOL. The target system is an IBM AS/400.

Comment: It would be really good if you told us the COBOL compiler that you are using and the OS that you are using. Why are you unable to try out such simple things yourself?

Comment: @BillWoodger I am not COBOL programmer so i don't have lot of idea regarding this But I deal with COBOL i need to this clarification :(

Comment: But what COBOL do you deal with? It can't just be a random one. You may not be a COBOL programmer, but someone is. Need to know which COBOL and which OS, and why you keep putting RPG as a tag.

Comment: @BillWoodger I am dealing with AMXW COBOL code on AS400 machines thats why i Put RPG there if it is incorrect i'll remove that Tag

Comment: RPG is a different language to Cobol.  You should only put the RPG tag on questions that relate to the RPG language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will continue into `PARA2` just as in your other question.

`EXIT` does nothing, in any circumstance.

If it were to do anything, it would be only when there was a `PERFORM` involved. If a `PERFORM` were involved, the programmer may think that `EXIT` has somewhere to return to. With a `GO TO`, where would `EXIT` go?

Exit does nothing. In any circumstance.

See here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=4f9b202f-fba2-4802-8d61-8e31aef22d0e&ps=25

I am assuming that you have an IBM Midrage COBOL, as you keep tagging your COBOL questions with RPG.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=4f9b202f-fba2-4802-8d61-8e31aef22d0e&ps=25

The above link describes the situation with CONTINUE, but CONTINUE and EXIT in current IBM compilers have identical function (no code is generated) as is also explained there.

So what do EXIT and CONTINUE do? They are both "No Operation" statements, but they must have some use?

They are for us. We use them if we otherwise have no statement that we can use, or as a reminder to ourselves of something that we expect to happen.

For instance, if site-standards do not allow the use of negation in an `IF` you may see this:

```
IF A EQUAL TO B
    CONTINUE
ELSE
    Do some stuff...
END-IF
```

There *must* be a statement after the `IF` but you don't actually want to do anything. Use `CONTINUE` and the `IF` will now compile and function exactly as you want.

You will also see things like this:

```
    PERFORM 300-PARA THRU 300-PARA-EXIT

    ...

300-PARA.

    ...

    IF some-condition
        GO TO 300-PARA-EXIT
    END-IF

    ...

300-PARA-EXUT.
     EXIT.
```

Because of the `PERFORM` range (the `THRU`) the `PERFORM` will end with the last statement of 300-PARA-EXIT. To avoid compiler diagnostics, a paragraph must contain something. Something that does nothing is `EXIT`.

Many people erroneously think that `CONTINUE` and `EXIT` actually do something. I have money which says they don't.

On IBM compilers there have been some changes in `EXIT` over the years. It used to be that `EXIT` could *only* appear in a paragraph on its own. It still generated no code, but could not be used interchangeably with `CONTINUE`. Whoopee! No longer true. That's me being ironic.

Comment: Thanks .. I got it. It sounds something Go To in COBOL just skipping the unwanted code.

Comment: @Siddharth `GO TO` is never needed, but when used, it is just for skipping code, like in any other language which has a `GO TO`.